# PHP session is getting lost completely when embedded using iframe on safari web browser

Tags: php, session, iframe, safari

I have a php application completely depend on sessions to carry data from one page to another. Users can embed it using iframe. My sessions are getting lost completely when user access it from safari web browser. This is only happening when my php application is embedded using iframe. Working fine in other web browsers.

Looking for suggestion that is actually working. I tried almost all suggestions available on stackoverflow, but none of them is working.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Never got any response or hint :(

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following header:

header('P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"');

Comment: This is not supported in newer version on Safari web browser.